# PHP $_SESSION unpredictably not set

Tags: php, session

I'm finding $_SESSION apparently not set, but the effects vary between different browsers / PCs. What works on FF fails on Chrome, what fails on FF on my desktop XP works on my laptop on XP.

I've pared the scripts down to the minimum, as shown below.

```
<?php
session_start();
define("_CMS_SYSTEMNAME", " Stock Reporting");
define("_CMS_TEST" , true);
define("_ROOT"              , $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) ;
define("_CMS_WELCOME"      , _ROOT."/admin/logon/welcome.htm");
define("_OUTERPAGE",_ROOT.'/admin/adminincludes/adminpages.htm' );


echo "Session Variables After Session Start : "; print_r($_SESSION); echo "<br>";

$Middle="../mydetails/mydetails.htm";
include(_OUTERPAGE);
?>
```

If I run this in folder A  (www.mytest.mydomain.co.uk/admin/FolderA/myscript.php)
then I get what I expect:

```
Session Variables After Session Start : Array ( [abidata] => YTo4Ontz{long string
of data}jAiO319 [Sess_LogonUserID] => 1 [Sess_Manuf] => [Sess_Prod] => 
[Sess_Code] => [Sess_OrderBy] => )
```

If I run this in folder B  (www.mytest.mydomain.co.uk/admin/FolderB/myscript.php)
then I get an empty result:

```
Session Variables After Session Start : Array ( )
```

I've tried changing the filenames, and it makes no difference, but changing the folder does.  My hosting support believe there is no way they can be treating any one folder differently, but it still appears to be only the folder which makes the difference.

I'm running short of ways to investigate this further.

Comment: Are you doing some specific call like `session_set_cookie_params`?

Comment: It seems your browser have Cookies disabled.

Comment: No, not using session_set_cookie_params. Also cookies are not disabled.  I have found a solution, but it still leaves questions unanswered.   See above

Comment: maybe htaccess or server mod changing the session/cookie depending on folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. 
Found a solution - of a sort.
We found another site with the same problem. Session Variables not set up on entry, but if the same script is run in a different folder then they are magically there.  (And it is nothing to do with include files - see script in original post there - aren't any at that point.)

The common factor is that both sites have a mod to change the timeout of the session variable.
    setcookie ('PHPSESSID', $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time()+150000);

This appears to somehow mess up the working of the session variables on a folder specific basis.  Deleting the cookie clears the problem.

Why this should be so I have no idea.